# write a program to read data from a file "marks.dat" which stores marks of 10 students in format "rno,name,marks".for ex:12,hazel,68

Tags: python, file-handling

Please tell me how can I take input in given format from the file and then calculate their average.

First of all I made a file named "marks.dat" in text format and then in my python I opened the file and read using `readlines()` function.

Then I stuck at only one thing that how can take input like "rno,marks,name".

Please resolve this problem.

Comment: Python comes with a module for [CSV](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) files (comma seperated values).

Comment: example of the file and your current code would help...

Comment: You could read each line of the file into a list of three values corresponding to those fields by using the [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) function. There's example code in the linked documentation.